# best python library to extract the location from the text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science-model

Which is the best python library to extract the location from the text. Spacy and NLTK not recognizing the mountain names, river bodies properly.

Could you please give me your suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you specify the language you are working with, and provide some examples that Spacy and NLTK cannot handle properly.

Comment: Also if you need very accurate NER for a specific kind of data you might have to annotate a training set and train your own model.

Comment: @noe I need it in english

Comment: For English Spacy and NLTK have state of the art NER models, don't expect to find anything better unless you train your own model.